# Copy an array of floats to array of Strings

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix, copy

```
#ADD STRING MATRIX AND NUM MATRIX Fraction(3).limit_denominator(10)from fractions import Fraction
#ONLY WORKS FOR SQUARE ONES RIGHT NOW!
from fractions import Fraction

def make1(nm,x):
    if nm[x][x]!=1:
        print("Divide R1 by ",Fraction(nm[x][x]).limit_denominator(10))
        tempr = multiply(nm[x],1/nm[x][x])
        nm[x] = tempr
    return nm

def convert(n):
    try:
        return float(n)
    except ValueError:
        num, denom = n.split('/')
        return float(num) / float(denom)

def convertm(m):
    lm = len(m)
    lx = len(m[0])
    tempn = [0]*lx
    temps = [[]]*lm
    print(temps)
    cnt = 0
    for x in m:
        tempn = x
        for n in x:
            temps[cnt].append(str(Fraction(n).limit_denominator(10)))
            print(n)
        cnt+=1
        print(temps)

def mprint(matrix):
    s = [[str(e) for e in row] for row in matrix]
    lens = [max(map(len, col)) for col in zip(*s)]
    fmt = '\t'.join('{{:{}}}'.format(x) for x in lens)
    table = [fmt.format(*row) for row in s]
    print('\n'.join(table))

def subtract(r1,r2): #r1-r2
    tempr = [0]*len(r1)
    for x in range (0,len(r1)):
        tempr[x] = r1[x]-r2[x]
    return tempr

def multiply(r1,n):
    tempr = [0]*len(r1)
    for x in range (0,len(r1)):
        tempr[x] = r1[x]*n
    return tempr

def ans(nm):
    end = len(nm[0])
    cnt = 0
    for x in nm:
        cnt+=1
        print("X",cnt,"=",x[end-1])

equ = int(input("How many equasions are in the linear system? "))
#unk = int(input("How many unkowns are in the linear system? "))
nm = [0] * equ
sm = [0] * equ
for x in range (0,equ):
    tempinput = input("Please enter line "+str(x+1)+" of the matrix: ")
    templist = [convert(n) for n in tempinput.split()]
    nm[x] = templist
    sm[x] = tempinput.split()

mprint(nm)

nm = make1(nm,0)

mprint(nm)

for p in range (0,equ-1):

    for x in range (p,equ-1):
        print("Subtract ",Fraction(nm[x+1][p]).limit_denominator(10),"*",p+1,"by",p+2)
        tempr = multiply(nm[p],nm[x+1][p])
        nm[x+1] = subtract(tempr,nm[x+1])
        print("FIRST X: ",x,"P",x)                
        mprint(nm)
        nm = make1(nm,p+1)
        mprint(nm)

#GOIN BACK
for p in range (0,equ-1):
    for x in range (0,equ-(p+1)):
        print("Subtract ",x,"by",Fraction(nm[x][2-p]).limit_denominator(10),"*",3)
        tempr = multiply(nm[2-p],nm[x][2-p])
        nm[x]= subtract(nm[x],tempr)
        print("SECOND X: ",x,"P",x)

    mprint(nm)

ans(nm)

##or x in range (0,equ):
  #  print()

#g = nm[1][0]-1
#print("")
#tempr = multiply(nm[0],g/nm[0][0])
#nm[0]=tempr
#tempr = subtract(nm[1],nm[0])
#nm[0] = tempr
```

[Pastebin of my code](http://pastebin.com/nXWZceAX)

Ok so where my actual problem is in the unimplemented (because I couldn't get it working) def convertm. What this is supposed to do is take the matrix with numbers (nm) and take every value and convert it into a string as fractions (x/x) if needed and store it in the matrix of strings (sm).
Here is that segment of code I am referencing...

```
def convertm(m):
    lm = len(m)
    lx = len(m[0])
    tempn = [0]*lx
    temps = [[]]*lm
    print(temps)
    cnt = 0
    for x in m:
        tempn = x
        for n in x:
            temps[cnt].append(str(Fraction(n).limit_denominator(10)))
            print(n)
        cnt+=1
        print(temps)
```

I added some prints in order to try and test what the heck was going on during it. I am getting an output of just the last row being repeated through all rows. I think I don't have a return statement currently just because I have been trying get this to work. Ok so for an example if an array is imported that is...

[ [1,2,3],

[4,5,6],

[7,8,9] ]

It will output (set temps to)

[ ['7','8','9'],

['7','8','9'],

['7','8','9'] ]

I want it to output (set temps to)

[ ['1','2','3'],

['4','5','6'],

['7','8','9'] ]

Also I am using Python 3.3.1

(probably should upgrade to 3.3.3 but that is not what we are discussing!)
I have absolutely no idea why it is doing this and any little bit of help would very appreciated!

THANK YOU

I also apologize if this formatting is horrible I am new to this and I copy/pasted this from another forum I am very desperate to know what is going on here.

Comment: I would remove the huge block of code at the top.  I completely ignored it to answer the question.  It will turn most users off from attempting to answer the question.

Comment: Generally, you'll get the best results when asking a question if you strip your code down to [the bare minimum necessary to run it and produce the error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
temps = [[]]*lm
```

makes a list of list, where each sublist *points to the same list in memory*.  So, if you modify one, you modify them all.  This is why you are seeing the behavior you are seeing.

Change it to

```
temps = [[] for _ in range(lm)] # xrange on python2
```

to get different sublists.

Comment: That worked thank you so much for the help! This solved a lot of frustration I have been going through!